# Do Korean sentences always end with a verb-like word?

Tags: word-order

I know Korean grammar usually requires sentences to end in a 'verby' word like an action verb (동사), descriptive verb (형용사), or 되다 (to become) or 이다(to be something). But can correct, full Korean sentences *ever* end in something else?

Comment: "네!" (Interjection)

Comment: Watch any gangster movie and you'll find out, any sentence can end with `ᄊ` (?)

Comment: Doesn't Korean have sentence-final particles?

Comment: @hippietrail do you mean something like -네요?

Comment: @topomorto: Maybe. It could be that what are regarded as sentence final particles in other Asian languages are regarded as part of verb conjugations/endings in Korean. (I'm no Korean expert, just an enthusiast with the barest tourist level in the language.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is reasonable to say that since full, grammatically correct English sentences (besides the usual one word "Yes.", "No.", and "Hello." expressions) always come with some form of verb, the same can be said for Korean.

However, comparisons to English might not be so sound since Korean and English are quite different. So, let's jump into something more universal: linguistics!

The notion that a sentence needs to have a verb or adjective is slightly incorrect only because [several types of sentences exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_(linguistics)). Thus, it's only fair to say that in any language, grammatically correct sentences can come in verb-less forms (See "Major and minor sentences" section of the wiki page).

But, in terms of simple sentences (sentences that **do** contain at least one subject and one predicate), it would be against that very definition of a grammatically correct sentence to come in a predicate-less form.

**TL;DR** Yes and no

Comment: What if the word order is switched? Is Korean necessarily SOV or is it just a strong tendency (like Latin used to be)?

Comment: The word order shouldn't affect the composition of a sentence, although you do pose an interesting question. This might require some more analysis on Korean word ordering roots, although I'm leaning towards Korean necessarily being SOV. The only reason I say this is because their choice of a word order reflects the Korean view on how expressions should be constructed, namely macro-to-micro. Other than that, my guess is as good as yours.

Answer (score 2):

Korean sentences can end with a verb 
한나는 집에 왔어요.

verb copula 
저는 학생입니다.

or an adjective
유나는 정말 예쁘다.

Further information can be found here 
http://www.linguajunkie.com/korean-2/make-korean-sentences

Comment: Do you mean Korean sentences end with nothing other than parts of speech shown in your examples?

Comment: How about `여기 요` in addition to that list?

Answer (score 0):

I think the order is not really SVO but it is accordingly to the correct placement  of the particles  on each noun use but  always ends in verbs because of their omission rules that  they have and since the most important part of the korean sentences are the predicatee  you might’ve noticed this in their dingle worded sentences like 사랑합니다 where in the subdct and object are ommoted but sty we inderst thst it means i love you oryou may arrange the sentence 내가 사과를 먹어요 /사과를 내가 먹어요 which still both translate to i eat apple whether the subject  or the object was written first or not but the  particles  that were attached to the nouns were in correct places and slways end in verbs becay of the omission rules that they have, theycould ommit any noun which are less important